# RabbitMQ delayed message plugin - How to show delayed message in admin UI?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We use the rabbitmq message delay plugin (rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange) for delaying messages. Is it possible for debugging and monitoring purposes, to show holded / delayed messages in rabbitmq admin web interface?

Link: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/

Bye,
Ben

Comment: What "rabbitmq admin web interface" are you using? Update your question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; delayed messages are not visible in the admin UI.

As an alternative you can route the messages to a real queue, with a TTL defined as well as dead lettering which will cause expired message to be routed to the final queue.

You can set a fixed TTL on the temporary queue or use the `expiration` property on individual messages.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So50760600Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50760600Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("", "temp", "foo", m -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setExpiration("5000");
                return m;
            });
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "final")
    public void in(String in, @Header("x-death") List<?> death) {
        System.out.println(in + ", x-death:" + death);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue temp() {
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("x-message-ttl", 10000); // default (max)
        args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "");
        args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "final");
        return new Queue("temp", true, false, false, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue finalQ() {
        return new Queue("final");
    }

}
```

and

```
foo:[{reason=expired, original-expiration=5000, count=1, exchange=, time=Fri Jun 08 10:43:42 EDT 2018, routing-keys=[temp], queue=temp}]
```

Comment: I tried to set the TTL with org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties.setExpiration(String expiration) on individual messages. But the message is not expired. The value for expiration is the time in ms?

Comment: Yes, ms; works fine for me; see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. My code doesn't work:

`MessageBuilder mb = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(msg); // copy msg <br/>
Message msgWithDelay = mb.build();
msgWithDelay.getMessageProperties().setExpiration("5000"); // Expiration ist not set in msg 
msgWithDelay.getMessageProperties().setHeader("TEST", "test"); // works
rabbitTemplate.send(msgWithDelay);`

Any tips?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference how you set the property; but why so complicated? Why not just `msg.getMessageProperties().setExpiration("5000")` ?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. I'm sending a msg with a delay to the Exchange. After the delay, the Msg goes into the queue. The consumer picks up the message, sets a long delay and sets a short expiration. More does not happen here.